# Python, How can I correctly pass the result of one function (specifically, a file) to another function?

Tags: python, function, file, ubuntu

I'm a beginner. I have written a Python program with the following pseduocode:

1. Define Function1.

a. This function takes a large single-fasta file (a genome) and splits it into pieces.

b. These pieces are written to a multi-fasta output file (ex. below).

2. Define Function2.

a. This function reads the lines of the multi-fasta file

b. Writes to an output file the fasta id followed by the length of the fasta entry.

most of the code:

```
from Bio import SeqIO
import io

def metagenome_simulator(genome_fasta, out_file):
    outfile = open(out_file, "a+b")
    fasta = SeqIO.parse(open(genome_fasta, "rU"), "fasta")
         #does the split, blah, blah - I know this function works on its own already
    len_file.close()
    fasta.close()
    return outfile

def contig_len_calculator(fasta, out_file):
    outfile = io.open(out_file, "wb")
    fhandle = io.open(fasta, "a+b")
    outfile.write("contig_id" + "\t" + "contig_length" + "\n")
    for entry in SeqIO.parse(fhandle, "fasta"):
        #calculates lengths, blah, blah - i know this works independently too
     outfile.close()
     fhandle.close()
     return

def main():
    output = metagenome_simulator(sys.argv[1], sys.argv[2])
    print(output)
    contig_len_calculator(output, sys.argv[3])

 main()
```

And my command (bash shell) would be:

```
./this_script.py genome_fasta_file split_fasta_out_file final_output_file.
```

The output would be two separate files, one for each function in the program. The first would be the split fasta:

```
>split_1
ATCG....
>split_2
ATCG....
.
.
.
```

And the second would be the lengths file:

```
>split_1    300
>split_2    550
.
.
.
```

This does not work. It runs Fuction1 just fine and makes the split_fasta_output file but then returns:

```
<open file 'out_file', mode 'a+b' at 0x7f54b8454d20>
Traceback (most recent call last):
File "./this_script.py", line 62, in <module>
main()
File "./this_script.py", line 60, in main
contig_len_calculator(output, sys.argv[3])
File "./this_script.py", line 47, in contig_len_calculator
fhandle = io.open(fasta, "a+b")
TypeError: invalid file: <open file 'out_file', mode 'a+b' at 0x7f54b8454d20>
```

I have no idea why it doesn't work. So my question is this: how do I properly pass a file created in one function to another function?

EDIT: Put the whole traceback error.

Comment: Hey Brandon, there's not quite enough information here to fully debug your problem. Can you include the full  stack trace for the TypeError?

Comment: edited, hopefully that helps. I just basically want to know how I can create a file in the first function (which I know works just fine, and makes the file and puts in in the cwd) and then pass that file as input to the second function to do something else to it.

Answer (score 2):

The problem is that `metagenome_simulator` returns a file descriptor, which you then try to pass into `io.open`. `io.open` takes either an integer file descriptor (`some_fd.fileno()`) or a path. The simple solution is then to return the path to your outfile, rather than the outfile itself.

```
def metagenome_simulator(genome_fasta, out_file):
    ...  # your code as-written
    return out_file
```

But if you like you could instead do:

```
def metagenome_simulator(genome_fasta, out_file):
    # completely as-written, including
    return outfile

def contig_len_calculator(fasta, out_file):
    outfile = io.open(out_file, "wb")
    fhandle = io.open(fasta.fileno(), "a+b")
    ...
```

The advantage of the first approach is that it makes the `out_file` and `fasta` arguments to `contig_len_calculator` have the same type, which seems sane.

Comment: @kindall you're right! I assumed the `len_file.close()` was an error copying his original code to a MCVE. My answer has been updated to illuminate the actual issue.

Comment: Well there is much more to the code (with a couple parameters in the original function I did not include), so there are a couple artefacts. Basically all I couldn't figure out is how to correctly pass files between functions. Thanks for the help!

Comment: @BrandonKieft I strongly recommend that you *not* do `f = open(filepath)`, pass it around, then `f.close()` later. However if that's the pattern you want to use then you're doing it perfectly. `io.open` doesn't take a file object, which was the problem.

Answer (score 0):

The `open` function takes a filename and returns a file object. `metagenome_simulator` returns a file object. You pass this as `fasta` and then use `open` on it. But you do not need to open it since it's already an open file and not just a filename.